# Exchange 2003->2010 Migration, Free/Busy issue

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-2003, public-folders

We just finished a migration from Exchange 2003 to 2010 (old servers have been removed from the org, wiped, etc) and most everything seems to be working. I do have an issue with Outlook 2003 users - they cannot view the Free/Busy information of other users. Running outlook with /cleanfreebusy results in a dialog stating that outlook is unable to clean the free/busy information on the server. Upgrading the user to Outlook 2010 had no impact. Users who were on Outlook 2007/2010 prior to shutting down the Exch 2003 machines do not seem to be affected.

I did find a KB article (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/945602/en-us) that seems to be relevant, but there already is a replica for the Exch2010 pub folder. However, it still has the old Exch org listed in free/busy... is this a problem? Should I just add a replica to that one? Should it be deleted?

```
get-publicfolder -Identity "\NON_IPM_SUBTREE\SCHEDULE+ FREE BUSY" -Recurse | fl name,Replicas


Name     : SCHEDULE+ FREE BUSY
Replicas : {}

Name     : EX:/o=ExchOrgName/ou=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT)
Replicas : {Public Folder Database 1878261148}

Name     : EX:/o=ExchOrgName/ou=OldAdminGroup
Replicas : {}
```

Comment: Any error messages? In the host computer event log or from Outlook? What about on the Exchange server?

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if you have more than one public folder in the AD schema. Easiest way is to go to  EMC and select Toolbox -> Public Folder Management Console. Then connect to the server. If you try to browse and get error for "Multiple MAPI public folder trees detected" you need to do the following:

1. Open ADSI edit and connect to Configuration naming context.
2. Copy the name of this context e.g. `CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=tld`
3. Run in cmd the following `LDIFDE -f c:\Config.txt -d "CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=tld"`.
   This will create a txt file with searchable configuration.
4. Search for `msExchPFTreeType`  containing value of `1`. These are active PF that may create problems for exchange and old Outlooks.
5. Go back to ADSI edit and find the given properties and change them to `0`. This will disable them and allow Public Folder Management Console to display the settings correctly.

After the migration we had 2 PF the one from Exchange 2010 in

```
CN=Public Folders,CN=Folder Hierarchies,CN=Exchange Administrative Group (FYDIBOHF23SPDLT),CN=Administrative Groups,CN=BRAVO,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,DC=dimain,DC=tld
```

and one from Exchange 2003 in:

```
CN=Public Folders,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=dimain,DC=tld
```

Also if you do not have such error you could check [this article](http://smtp25.blogspot.com/2007/08/no-freebusy-information-could-be.html) to redirect the PF server for the administrative group.